# How to hide part of page with ASP Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to use Entity Framework in my MVC project and I wonder how I can show/hide a part of a page to users with a certain role?  Right now I only know that I can hide controllers / actions behind `[authorize]`, but I'm wondering how I could only hide part of a page?

For example: only an admin can see the 'delete' button on a post another user made. Or another example: user can upvote posts, but not if they themselves made that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code like this, based on the roles:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    <div>
      Hidden content for users
    </div>
}
```

Also you could use this helper function with HTML helpers, which show element based on condition:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Show(this MvcHtmlString value, bool condition)
{
     return condition? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

So you can hide delete link like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Home").Show(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```